# How to optimise merging two queries that return the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and looking to write a function that finds a match on Table A or Table B and return the columns from Table A. However, I am finding it runs very slow.

Here is that I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_custom_function(search text)
 RETURNS SETOF table_a
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
    SELECT table_a.*
    FROM table_a
    LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.my_id = table_b.my_id
    WHERE table_a.name = search OR table_b.name = search
    ORDER BY table_a.name DESC
$function$
```

Searching Table A, then Table B and merging the results in code takes about ~50ms. But the above query takes over ~600ms.

Are there any ways I can do this? I have a feeling I don't need to join, but instead a union or to combine the two queries.

Here is an example of data, search and result.

Table A Rows

- name: "Banana", person_id: 1,
- name: "Apple", person_id: 1,
- name: "Orange" person_id: 2,
- name: "Nut", person_id: 3,
- name: "Avocado", person_id: 3,
- name: "Carrot", person_id: 4

Table B Rows

- person_id: 1, name: "James"
- person_id: 2, name: "Harry"
- person_id: 3, name: "Sarah",
- person_id: 4, name: "Jed"

Like/Fuzzy Search the character "e" provides results:

- name: "Banana", person_id: 1 [person name match]
- name: "Apple", person_id: 1 [fruit name match]
- name: "Orange", person_id: 2 [fruit name match]
- name: "Carrot", person_id: 4 [person name match]

Another way to phrase my problem would be, how do I merge the following two queries into one SQL query?

```
SELECT table_a.*
FROM table_a
WHERE table_a.name = 'my search'
ORDER BY table_a.name DESC
```

and

```
SELECT table_a.*
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.my_id = table_b.my_id
WHERE table_b.name = 'my search'
ORDER BY table_a.name DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help get your question across.  Side note: Your left join, as written, will behave identically to an inner join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: Your current query can return multiple copies of a row in A if it matches multiple times into B.  Is that desirable? Necessary?